# z-index Drupal 7 Skeleton Boilerplate discriminating roles?

Tags: users, theming

I'm building a website using Drupal 7 for the first time. I have always built them on Drupal 6 using the basic theme to build my own custom themes from. This time I decided to change, because I thought it was time to move onto Drupal 7 and I wanted responsive design for this project.

I have a custom front---page template, and on that front page I have views slideshow (cycle) and wanted to place text on it. So i made a block with such text, and gave it a z-index 999 and an absolute position, when the slider has a z-index -999. Everything looks just as I want it and expect it to, until.... I log out! Is it possible that the css is discriminating roles?

How can it possibly be that logged in as admin I see the slider on the bottom and the block on top as expected, and as an anonymous user the text block is hidden underneath the slider? (And I know it is because when I resize, I can partially see it, as it moves down.... ) I'm lost.

Edit for more info: this is happening in IE9, Chrome, Safari mac, Safari Win, and Firefox is displacing the Slider onto the right....GRRRR. HELP!
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you cleared the drupal cache?

Comment: Volker. Thanks for asking. I cleared the caché, but also I added position: relative; to both items. Apparently that was the issue as well. Although the cache clearing might have helped as well.

Comment: However, Firefox is still displacing the slider to what would be the "one_half_last" position (the block has the class "one_half" and I added a "clear" class right after. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was too quick to post the question and I apologize, since the answer is all over the internet, and for those going through the same issue:

**YOU MUST add position relative or absolute to all items** involved in the z-indexing. Ot the z-index won't work.

Also why was Firefox not rendering things right? I had added a skeleton class to the search box template, but had not added a clear right after.

As to why it was rendering things right when i was logged in as an admin, but not when I was anonymous, remains a mystery.

Hope this is useful for those having identical issues.